# Lebesgue points of a function is not affected by multiplication of the integrand with a smooth function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $S^1$ be the circle, let us consider a function $f(x,t): S^1 \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^T \int_{S^1} \lvert f(x,t) \rvert dxdt <\infty
\end{equation}
for an arbitrary $T \in (0,\infty)$

Now, let us define
\begin{equation}
F_\phi(t):=\int_0^t \int_{S^1} \phi(x)f(x,s)dxds
\end{equation}
for each $\phi \in C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb{R})$. Then, for each $\phi$, it is of course obvious that $F_\phi : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable almost everywhere. Let us denote the collection of such points as $\mathcal{A}_\phi \subset [0,\infty)$.

Then, is it still true that
\begin{equation}
[0,\infty) - \cap_{\phi \in C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb{R})} \mathcal{A}_\phi
\end{equation}
is a null set?

I tried to analyze the Lebesgue points and how they are obtained, but it seems much more nontrivial and non-constructive..

Could anyone pleaes help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a null set.

Pick a sequence of continuous functions $f_n: S^1 \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_1\leq 4^{-n}.$ Let $g_n(t)=\int_{S^1}|f(x,t)-f_n(x,t)|dx.$ Let $Z=\bigcap_m\bigcup_{n\geq m} \{s:(Mg_n)(s)>2^{-n}\text{ or }g_n(s)>2^{-n}\}$ where $M$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator on $L^1(\mathbb R),$ applied in the $t$ co-ordinate. Then $Z$ is a null set and $t\not\in Z\implies t \in \mathcal A_\phi.$

This is an explicit version of the set given by the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function proofs of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, with an integral stuck in. See the [proof on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) or https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/245a-notes-5-differentiation-theorems/. Warning: you want Lebesgue points as on Wikipedia, or one-sided weak Lebesgue points as in the notes. A two-sided weak Lebesgue point, like in Stein and Shakarchi's real analysis book, is not quite enough. Though the proof can be modified to get a true Lebesgue point.

I don't think the $\phi$ adds any difficulty except extra notation.
Here is some detail on why $t\not\in Z\implies t \in \mathcal A_\phi.$  By scaling, assume $|\phi(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in S^1.$ We need to show that $F_\phi$ is differentiable at $t.$ It suffices to establish the limit
$$\tfrac 1 h\int_{[t,t+h]}\int_{S^1}\phi(x)f(x,s)dx\,ds\to \int_{S^1}\phi(x)f(x,t)dx\text{ as }h\to 0\tag{1}$$
and similarly with $[t,t+h]$ replaced by $[t-h,t].$

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Since $t\not\in Z,$ there exists $m$ such that for $n\geq m$ we have $(Mg_n)(t)\leq 2^{-n}$ and $g_n(t)\leq 2^{-n}.$ Pick $n\geq m$ also satisfying $2^{-n}<\epsilon/4.$ Write (1) as $L_1(h)+L_2(h)\to R_1(h)+R_2(h)$ where $L_1(h)+L_2(h)$ splits the left-hand-side sum into $f_n$ and $f-f_n$ parts, and $R_1+R_2$ splits the right-hand-side similarly. $L_1(h)\to R_1(h)$ as $h\to 0$ by continuity of $t\mapsto \int_{S^1}\phi(x)f_n(x,t)dx,$ so $|L_1(h)-R_1(h)|<\epsilon/4$ for small enough $h.$ We have
\begin{align*}
|L_2(h)|
&=\left|\tfrac 1 h\int_{[t,t+h]}\int_{S^1}\phi(x)(f(x,s)-f_n(x,s))dx\,ds\right|\\
&\leq \tfrac 1 h\int_{[t,t+h]}\int_{S^1}|f(x,s)-f_n(x,s)|dx\,ds\\
&\leq 2(Mg_n)(t)<\epsilon/2.\end{align*}
And
\begin{align*}|R_2(h)|
&=\left|\int_{S^1}\phi(x)(f(x,t)-f_n(x,t))dx\right|\\
&\leq\int_{S^1}|f(x,t)-f_n(x,t)|dx\\
&= g_n(t)<\epsilon/4.
\end{align*}
So $|L_1(h)+L_2(h)-R_1(h)-R_2(h)|<\epsilon$ for small $h.$ Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary this gives (1).